# JQUERY JSON returned undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I m trying to write a reservation based on PHPJabbers' free script and unable to output the price when user selected a date. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
/**
 * @@@
 * DateTimePicker / Available Calendar (version)
 */
'use strict';

(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {
    var plugin_name = 'calendar',
            data_key = 'plugin_' + plugin_name,
            defaults = {
                modifier: 'datetimepicker', // wrapper class
                day_name: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'], //  0-6 = sunday -> saturday
                day_first: 0,
                month_name: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                paging: ['<i class="prev"></i>', '<i class="next"></i>'],
                unavailable: [], // static data - to merge with dynamic data
                adapter: null, // host to get json data of unavailable date
                month: null, // month of calendar = month in js + 1, month in js = 0-11
                year: null, // year of calendar
                num_next_month: 0, // number of next month to show
                num_prev_month: 0, // number of prev month to show
                num_of_week: 6, // number of week need to show on calendar number/auto
                price: null,
                onSelectDate: function(date, month, year){} // trigger on select
            };

    var Plugin = function(options){
        var date = new Date();

        this.options = options;
        this.$element = $(options.element);
        this.options.year = this.$element.data('year') || this.options.year || date.getFullYear();
        this.options.month = this.$element.data('month') || this.options.month || date.getMonth() + 1;
        this.options.month--;
        //this.options.price = 0;

        // for plugin
        this.unavailable = []; // for check for unavailable dates
        //this.price = 0;
        this.init.call(this);
        return this;
    };

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            var _this = this;

            // re-sort day_name & create day_index
            this.day_index = [];
            this.options.day_name = this.options.day_name.slice(this.options.day_first).concat(this.options.day_name.slice(0, this.options.day_first));
            for (var i = 0; i < this.options.day_name.length; i++){
                this.day_index.push((this.options.day_first + i + 7) % 7);
            }
            this.update();
        },

        /**
         * Update data, get json from adapter, generate search keywords & send to adapter
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        update: function(){
            var _this = this, months = this.getMonths();

            // get data
            if (typeof this.options.adapter === 'string'){
                $.getJSON(this.options.adapter, {
                    keys: $(months).map(function(item){
                        // format search key from js to database store
                        return this.year + '-' + (this.month <= 8?'0':'') + (this.month + 1);
                    }).toArray()
                }, function(data){
                    //console.log('update', data);
                    _this.unavailable = _this.options.unavailable.concat(data);
                    _this.draw(months);
                });
            }else{
                this.unavailable = this.options.unavailable;
                this.draw(months);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Draw months list to element
         * @param  {[type]} months array of {month: ..., year: ...} object
         * @return {[type]}        [description]
         */
        draw: function(months){
            this.$element.empty();
            for (var i in months){
                this.$element.append(this.getCalendar(months[i].month, months[i].year));
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get list of months need to show
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        getMonths: function(){
            var date = new Date(), result = [];
            for (var i = this.options.month - this.options.num_prev_month; i <= this.options.month + this.options.num_next_month; i++){
                date.setFullYear(this.options.year);
                date.setMonth(i);
                result.push({
                    month: date.getMonth(),
                    year: date.getFullYear()
                });
            }
            return result;
        },

        /**
         * Load previous month
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        prevMonth: function(){
            this.options.month--;
            this.update();
        },

        /**
         * Load next month
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        nextMonth: function(){
            this.options.month++;
            this.update();
        },

        /**
         * [getCalendar description]
         * @param  {[type]} month 0 - 11 (Jan - Dec)
         * @param  {[type]} year  full year
         * @return {[type]}       dom element
         */
        getCalendar: function(month, year){
            var _this = this, date = new Date();
            date.setFullYear(year);
            date.setMonth(month);
            date.setDate(1);

            var day_first = date.getDay();

            // total date
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
            date.setDate(0);
            var total_date = date.getDate();

            // begin date
            var date_start = this.day_index.indexOf(day_first);

            // total week need to show
            var total_week;
            if (!isNaN(this.options.num_of_week)){
                total_week = 6;
            }else{
                total_week = Math.ceil((date_start + total_date)/7);
            }

            // draw
            return $('<div>').addClass(this.options.modifier).append([
                $('<div>').addClass('paging').append(function(){
                    return [
                        $('<span>').addClass('prev').append(_this.options.paging[0]).click(function(){
                            _this.prevMonth();
                        }),
                        $('<div>').addClass('month-name').append([_this.options.month_name[date.getMonth()], ', ', date.getFullYear()]),
                        $('<span>').addClass('next').append(_this.options.paging[1]).click(function(){
                            _this.nextMonth();
                        }),
                    ];
                }),
                $('<table>').append(function(){
                    return [
                        $('<thead>').append(function(){
                            return $(_this.options.day_name).map(function(index, element){
                                return $('<td>').append(element);
                            }).toArray();
                        }),
                        $('<tbody>').append(function(){
                            var ap = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < total_week; i++){
                                ap.push($('<tr>').append(function(){
                                    var ap = [];
                                    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                                        var d = new Date();
                                        d.setFullYear(year);
                                        d.setMonth(month);
                                        //console.log(month, year);
                                        //d.setDate(1);
                                        d.setDate(-date_start + (j + 1)+(i*7));
                                        //var available = me.options.filter.call(me, d);
                                        ap.push($('<td>').addClass(function(){
                                            var cls = [];
                                            if (_this.isAvailable(d.getDate(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getFullYear())){
                                                cls.push('available');
                                            }else{
                                                cls.push('unavailable');
                                            }
                                            if (d.getMonth() == date.getMonth()){
                                                cls.push('cur-month');
                                            }else{
                                                cls.push('near-month');
                                            }
                                            return cls.join(' ');
                                        }).data({date: d.getDate(), month: d.getMonth() + 1, year: d.getFullYear()}).append(d.getDate()).click(function(){
                                            var date = $(this).data('date'),
                                            month = $(this).data('month'),
                                            year = $(this).data('year');
                                            _this.options.onSelectDate.call(_this, date, month, year);
                                        }));
                                    }
                                    return ap;
                                }));    
                            }
                            return ap;
                        })
                    ];
                })

            ]);
        },

        /**
         * Check the date book: date, month, year have to in MySql format
         * Base on this.unavailable data / input MySql date format (support glob)
         * Eg: ['year-month-date', '*-month-date']
         * @param  {[type]}  date  [description]
         * @param  {[type]}  month month in javascript = 0-11, month in MySql = 1-12, so month input have to +1 before run this function
         * @param  {[type]}  year  [description]
         * @return {Boolean}       [description]
         */
        isAvailable: function(date, month, year){
            for (var i in this.unavailable){
                var book_date = this.unavailable[i].split('-');
                if (book_date.length !== 3){
                    return false;
                }else if (
                    (book_date[0] == '*' || book_date[0] - year === 0)  &&
                    (book_date[1] == '*' || book_date[1] - month === 0) &&
                    (book_date[2] == '*' || book_date[2] - date === 0)
                ){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Get the price of the selected date
         * @param  {[type]}  date  [description]
         * @param  {[type]}  month month in javascript = 0-11, month in MySql = 1-12, so month input have to +1 before run this function
         * @param  {[type]}  year  [description]
         */
        getPrice: function(date, month, year) {
            // get data
            $.getJSON("assets/calendar/server/pricelist.php", {
                keys: year + '-' + month + '-' + date
            }, function(data){
                //_this.unavailable = _this.options.unavailable.concat(data);
                //_this.draw(months);
                this.options.price = data;
                //alert(data);
                console.log('success 1', data);
                return data;
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn[plugin_name] = function (options){
        return this.each(function(){
            var data = $(this).data(data_key);
            if (!data){
                $(this).data(data_key, new Plugin($.extend({
                    element: this
                }, defaults, options)));
            }
            if (typeof options === 'string'){
                $(this).data(data_key)[options].call(this);
            }
        });
    };
}));
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="col-xss-12 tab-pane active" id="all">
                        <div data-form-alert>
                            <div id="all-room-alert" class="data-form-alert-success" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <div id="all-room-alert-msg" class="alert alert-success text-center"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="show-next-month-all" data-toggle="calendar"></div>
                    </div>
    <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/calendar/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/calendar/scripts/dateTimePicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#show-next-month-all').calendar(
            {
                num_next_month: 2,
                num_prev_month: 0,
                adapter: 'assets/calendar/server/adapter.php',
                onSelectDate: function(date, month, year)
                {
//                    alert([year, month, date].join('-') + ' is: ' + this.isAvailable(date, month, year));
                    document.getElementById("all-room-alert").style.visibility = "visible";
                    if(this.isAvailable(date, month, year)) {
                        var price = this.getPrice(date, month, year);
                        console.log('success', price);
//                        alert(this.price);
                        document.getElementById("all-room-alert-msg").className = "alert alert-success text-center";
                        document.getElementById("all-room-alert-msg").innerText = [year, month, date].join('-') + ' is available and the price is ' + price;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("all-room-alert-msg").className = "alert alert-danger text-center";
                        document.getElementById("all-room-alert-msg").innerText = [year, month, date].join('-') + ' is not available';
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

The php file : (just for test)

```
echo(json_encode(array("IDR2,670,000")));
```

Now, the error that I got is price is undefined but when i look at the console, the data is there, just lagged behind.

When i try to output through console, the 'success' got undefined then below that line, i got 'success 1' and the price from the PHP file.

EDIT: Found out how to do it. Pretty much inside DatePicker.js, I added a new function called getPrice() and it takes in parameters date, month, year, alert-box-id. After calling getJson is done, it will append the result to the alert box.

Comment: Is that really a [**"Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable"**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example ?

Comment: Ok I found out how to do it. Pretty much just append it to the existing line

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode((your array), 1) and check the value of price.